# ASCII stored in String to Number in Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I have the the ascii value of the integer number stored in string variable in arduino sketch  and I want to convert it to the integer number. How do I do this?

```
String a = "59"; // or, 0x32,  ASCII value of integer number 2

const char * s = &a[0];

int num = atoi(s);
```

I expected the num to be 2 (the number corresponding the ascii 59)

But, when I print '`num`' in serial monitor, I am getting it to be 59 (Not 2).

Comment: a != 2 your type is string not integer

Comment: The ASCII value of integer number 2 in decimal is `"50"` not `"59"`

Comment: Assuming that `num` will always hold the ASCII value of a digit, you can use `int digit = num-'0';` to get the numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your integer to char, when sending it.  As in:

```
int x = atoi("50");
Serial.write((char)x);
```